# Capybara: won't select bootstrap button group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpath, selenium, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have the following button group that I cannot get Capybara w/ Selenium to select for:

```
<div class="btn-group hidden-sm" data-toggle-name="user[attributes][0][customization_id]" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default active">
    <input type="radio" value="17">
      Stocky body
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" value="16">
      Round body
  </label>
</div>
```

I have tried to following:

```
click_button 'Stocky body'

find(:xpath, "//input[@value='16']").click
```

and

```
find(:xpath, "//input[@type='radio'][@value='16']").click
```

At this point I've ready over an hour of :xpath and Capybara answers and they all see to be saying that the :xpath code should at least work.

Can anyone shed light on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution, because input tags aren't closed I need to use Capybara and find the  tags.

The following code was able to work:

```
page.find('label', text: 'Stocky body').click
```

Hope this helps anyone else trying to use Capybara with Bootstrap-styled selectors!

Comment: Wow, thanks so much!  Have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't [click_button a function](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)? So use `click_button('Stocky body')` in stead. And then "Stocky body" is not a button. At least not one as specified by html.

Also, your html is mall-formatted potentially causing a problem with your xpath. Your input tags are not closed.

Comment: click_button doesn't work on the btn-group styling unfortunately. I found the solution below. Thanks for helping out though!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, most likely to future me, one reason Capybara's **choose** may not be working is because your labels aren't inline.

In my case with Capybara, Simple Form, and Bootstrap [this post](http://davesouthard.com/tdd/cabybara/twitter/bootstrap/choose/radio_button/simple-form/2014/04/29/capybara-choose-bootstrap-option.html) describes the problem and solution